# VBA Function to fill column with split entries that are unique

Tags: vba, excel, unique

I am in need of help creating a very specific VBA function.
I need a function that will both split a cell's values and populate another column with unique values.

I am currently using `=IFERROR(INDEX(List,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,List),0,0),0)),"")` in order to get unique values out of one column to another.
Unfortunately, some of these values will be concatenated with a "," but still need to be unique.

Unfortunately, my knowledge of VBA is far from extensive. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have data like:

[image]

In column **A**.  Running this macro will extract uniques and put then in column **B**:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim c As Collection, K As Long
    Set c = New Collection
    K = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        ary = Split(r.Text, ",")
        For Each a In ary
            c.Add a, CStr(a)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Cells(K, "B").Value = a
            K = K + 1
            Else
                Err.Number = 0
            End If
        Next a
    Next r
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Here is the same logic in **UDF** form:

```
Public Function UniKues(rIn As Range)
    Dim c As Collection, K As Long
    Set c = New Collection
    K = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rIn
        ary = Split(r.Text, ",")
        For Each a In ary
            c.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next a
    Next r

    ReDim bry(1 To c.Count, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        bry(i, 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i
    UniKues = bry
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

[image]

Just hi-light a section of column **B** and enter the **UDF** in *Array* form

**EDIT#2**

Here is the **UDF** with **chris neilsen's** suggestions:

```
Public Function UniKues(rIn As Range)

    Dim c As Collection, K As Long, MM As Long
    Dim CC As Long
    Set c = New Collection
    K = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rIn
        ary = Split(r.Text, ",")
        For Each a In ary
            c.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next a
    Next r
    MM = Application.Caller.Rows.Count
    CC = c.Count
    dimn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MM, CC)
    ReDim bry(1 To dimn, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To CC
        bry(i, 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i
    If MM > CC Then
        For i = CC + 1 To MM
            bry(i, 1) = ""
        Next i
    End If
    UniKues = bry
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: This is excellent! Is there any way this can be used as an updating function, instead of a macro?

Comment: @matchai  Yes...............but it will take me a while to create the code........it would by a **UDF** that returns an *array.*

Comment: This is incredible! Works perfectly. For my last bit of bother, in the event of "#N/A", how would I go about making those cells blank?

Comment: I use a *helper* column:     **=IFERROR(B1,"")**

Comment: To avoid the NA's you need to return an array the same size as the on sheet array, which can be accessed with `Application.Caller`. Just pad the return array with `Empty`

Comment: @chrisneilsen  **THANKS** .............I'll play with it for a while......do you have any *link'ed* examples??

Comment: Pretty sure I've answered a Q with that technique before

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It appears having only one value in the list will populate the entire output with that same value. Is there a simple fix?

Comment: **YES**  I will get back to you in a couple of hours.